# Match speed of UITableView cell expansion animation with CAAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit, core-animation

I have a tableview whose cells change size. I animate the size change by

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

One of the properties of one of the subviews of the cell I need to animate is a `CAShapeLayer`'s `path` property. I animate its size in the `layoutSubviews` method of its parent view thusly

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];
  self.shapeLayer.frame = self.bounds;
  CGPathRef p = [self bezierPathForOverlay].CGPath;
  if (/*something irrelevant to this question is true*/) {
    CABasicAnimation *basicAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    basicAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue value:start
                                 withObjCType:@encode(CGPathRef)];
    NSValue *pW = [NSValue value:p
                    withObjCType:@encode(CGPathRef)];
    basicAnimation.toValue = pW;
    [self.shapeLayer addAnimation:basicAnimation
                           forKey:FKCShapeAnimationPath];
  }
  self.shapeLayer.path = p;
}
```

My understanding is that because I don't set a duration, the duration of the implicit `CATransaction` that the system has created will be used, and the shape should change size at the same speed as the cell. Any other properties relating to the timing that I didn't set would be treated similarly.

In practice, however, though the speed is close, it does not seem to be the same, leading to unsightly visual artifacts.

I'm hoping to avoid a solution that involves "in current versions of iOS the duration/animation curve for this animation is this, hard code it" -- in summary, my question is: How can I exactly match animation properties of system animations with Core Animation animations?